# Skipping for Query

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-query-language

Recently I've found special word "skipping" which works in query. I accidentally found out about it. This formula works:

```
=QUERY(A1:A11,"select A skipping 2")
```

It skips 1 row, gives me rows 1, 3, 5, 7... and so on. `Skipping 1` returns all the rows, `skipping 3` returns 1, 4, 7, 10...

[image]

I wonder if there any expressions in google-sheets query, that are not listed in [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage). And if someone else used or found "skipping" for queries.

Comment: good spot Max, how did you find out about it?  I set up an example sheet to show one way I can see it being useful: https://goo.gl/NQiHsG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is visible on the message you receive for a QUERY syntax error:

`"Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROREncountered "(" at line 1, column 41. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ...`**"skipping"** `... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "," ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ..."`

Sadly I think that means there aren't any other hidden clauses for us to find since the others are all mentioned on the guidance page.