Pickup n columns following a pattern
I try to find a nice way to select columns following a specific pattern.. the columns I want appear in my example every 3 columns (Col2, Col5, Col8)
Start Data




kwh
Price
Price per kwh
kwh
Price
Price per kwh
kwh
Price
Price per kwh





2022
2022
2022
2023
2023
2023
2024
2024
2024


Jan
1570
236,9
0,16
1199
204,3
0,18
1689
389
0,24


Feb
1590
241,2
0,16
1465
284,1
0,2
1151
281,4
0,25


Mar
873
131,8
0,16
928
187,4
0,21
967
242
0,26


Apr
771
117,2
0,16
903
179,5
0,2
639
158,8
0,25


May
290
42,1
0,15
476
91,5
0,2
586
135,4
0,24


Jun
229
32,7
0,15
279
51
0,19
282
71,9
0,26


Jul
210
29,9
0,15
256
47,4
0,19
277
65
0,24


Aug
159
21
0,14
198
40,8
0,21
230
54,9
0,24


Sept
209
29,9
0,15
260
55,5
0,22
263
62,6
0,24


Oct
342
51
0,15
259
55,3
0,22
401
96,8
0,25


Nov
567
86,8
0,16
811
180,7
0,23
683
204,7
0,3


Dec
1632
267,5
0,17
1541
356
0,24
1051
261,7
0,25



Expected Data




2022
2023
2024




Jan
1570
1199
1689


Feb
1590
1465
1151


Mar
873
928
967


Apr
771
903
639


May
290
476
586


Jun
229
279
282


Jul
210
256
277


Aug
159
198
230


Sept
209
260
263


Oct
342
259
401


Nov
567
811
683


Dec
1632
1541
1051



I can make it easy and to a simple manual VSTACK ={vstack(A2:A14)\vstack(B2:B14)\vstack(E2:E14)\vstack(H2:H14)}) or CHOOSECOLS or a QUERY assigning each columns I need.
I am looking for a solution where the n pattern is more dynamic, I explored a solution using SEQUENCE and CHOOSECOLS, this solution =LET(table;A2:J14;interval;3;{CHOOSECOLS(table;1)\CHOOSECOLS(table;SEQUENCE(1;(COLUMNS(table)-1)/interval;2;interval))}) is great but I am sure there can be other ways out of my reach like using INDIRECT, ADDRESS...storing values in accumulators and stuff like that.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

I edited the page as you suggested

Good.  Have an upvote!


You may try:
=filter(B5:K17;(B4:K4="")+(B4:K4="kwh"))

OR
=choosecols(B5:K17;1;sequence(3;1;2;3))



Thanks! The second one you proposed surely was a bit more simpler than mine!

Stuck on a low internet connection recently and I have to say, this image took a minute+ to load. I think almost all of the points in this answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 also apply to answers(Attn to point 3; Images are large and hard to read on mobile devices, and often cost mobile users valuable data.). I believe it was player0 who started this image trend. But I wish people would stop uploading images for every answer they post or if they do, at least not make them inline.

You can use QUERY's skipping. But it works only on rows. To use on columns, TRANSPOSE it:
Input:



$1.00
$2.00
$3.00
$4.00
$5.00
$6.00
$7.00
$8.00
$9.00
$10.00
$11.00
$12.00
$13.00
$14.00
$15.00













$16.00
$17.00
$18.00
$19.00
$20.00
$21.00
$22.00
$23.00
$24.00
$25.00
$26.00
$27.00
$28.00
$29.00
$30.00











$31.00
$32.00
$33.00
$34.00
$35.00
$36.00
$37.00
$38.00
$39.00
$40.00
$41.00
$42.00
$43.00
$44.00
$45.00












Function:
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:Z3),"Skipping 3"))

Output:



$1.00
$4.00
$7.00
$10.00
$13.00




$16.00
$19.00
$22.00
$25.00
$28.00


$31.00
$34.00
$37.00
$40.00
$43.00




This definitely works when I tried it with the OP's data. However, may I ask what reference you used for this? I tried searching for the term skipping from Google's official documentation but I cannot find it.

@PatrickdC One of the legends here, MaxMakhrov found it and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936369/skipping-for-query Good times...

Oh wow, and he found it by accident. So apparently, the term skipping is present on the error message (based on the accepted answer on that post) and yet it is absent on the official documentation.

@PatrickdC Yes.. many such things are found by developers(another classic would be e.range has rowStart and rowEnd keys..)  That's what SO answers and questions are supposed to provide.. not some free service answers that only benefit the asker... but things that benefit the entire community.
